# Getting a List of dates given a start and end date

Tags: java, loops, date

Given two dates (a start date and an end date in the form of M,YYYY), I want to make an arraylist with each element a date in the form M,YYYY between the starting and end date, inclusively.

For example, given dates 10,2010 and 2,2011 my list should look like this:

```
list = {(10,2010),(11,2010),(12,2010),(1,2011),(2,2011)};
```

I can do this by creating a while loop(while startYear < endYear), account for the starting month, for loop to 12th month, insert date into list, etc.

But I feel there has to be a more efficient way of going about this as this would require multiple checks for the starting month and end year. Is there a better solution that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @assylias JAVA, sorry I forgot to include that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would make more sense to store the dates as objects instead of "pairs" of year, month. For example, using the [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class in the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API (Java 8 and later):

```
YearMonth from = YearMonth.of(2010, 10);
YearMonth to = YearMonth.of(2011, 2);
List<YearMonth> list = new ArrayList<> ();

for (YearMonth ym = from; !ym.isAfter(to); ym = ym.plusMonths(1)) {
  list.add(ym);
}
```

Or to use the [stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) (not sure that it is much cleaner in this case):

```
List<YearMonth> list = Stream.iterate(from, ym -> ym.plusMonths(1))
                             .limit(MONTHS.between(from, to) + 1)
                             .collect(toList());
```